# Proof that applying the difference operator to a $d$-degree polynomial $d$ times yields $d!a_d$

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

Let $L$ be the [lag operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lag_operator) and $\triangledown:=(1-L)$ be the [difference operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lag_operator), that is, given a polynomial $p(t)$, we have 
$$L(p(t))=p(t-1)\qquad \triangledown(p(t))=p(t) - p(t-1)$$

> I am interested in proving that
>   $$
> \triangledown^d \sum_{i=0}^{d}a_it^i = a_dd!
> $$

It can be shown that $c<d \implies \triangledown^dt^c=0$. Hence, the above polynomial should (?) be equivalent to
$$
\triangledown^da_dt^d 
$$
which, together with the linearity of the difference operator, suggests that the problem is equivalent to prove that
$$
a_d(\triangledown^dt^d) = (a_d)d! 
$$ 
that is
$$
\triangledown^dt^d = d! 
$$ 
or, equivalently
$$
\triangledown^dt^d = (1-L)^dt^d=\sum_{k=0}^{d}(-1)^{d-k}\binom{d}{k}L^k(t)^d = d! \iff
$$ 
$$
\triangledown^dt^d = (1-L)^dt^d=\sum_{k=0}^{d}(-1)^{d-k}\binom{d}{k}(t-k)^d = d!
$$ 
but from this point I am stuck.
I would like to tag the entry with a Lag-operator tag but do not have sufficient reputation yet.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try with monomials

Comment: Thank you Exodd. Would you mind to elaborate a bit?

Comment: The $-1$ must have the same exponent of $L$ in the sum. For the conclusion, you can take the polinomial $(1-L)^dt^d-d!$ that has degree at maximum $d$, and show that it has $d+1$ roots, so that it's identically zero

Comment: Another way is by induction: try to show that, if $p(t)$ is a $n$ degree monic polynomial, then $\triangledown p(t)$ has degree $n-1$ and his leading coefficient is $n$

Comment: Thanks Exodd. I actually first attempted to prove the proposition by means of induction but with the wrong expansion of (1-B)^d - the correct form of which you pointed out to me! Thanks I'll try this!

Answer (score 2):

The only term in that series that doesn't go to zero on differentiating $d$ times is the $a_d$ term. When you differentiate $(a_d\cdot t^d)$ $d$ times, you get $a_d \cdot d!$

Comment: Thank you Tadatmya. However, I am interested in differencing a polynomial and not differentiating the polynomial. I must have written the title wrong.

Comment: From my understanding difference operator is only used with time series data and my that I mean discrete data at sampled intervals of time. So it is not clear to me how you can apply the lag or the difference operator to this polynomial.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply Tadatmya.  Applying the lag operator once on a polynomial  $ t^d $ yields $(t-1)^d$. I have elaborated the question a bit so maybe it becomes more intuitive.